# Jquery mobile page not opening php file

Tags: php, html, jquery-mobile

am trying to submit a form from a jquery-mobile page to a php file for processing but whenever i press the submit button it displays an "Error Loading Page" dialog.

I have tried looking at the [w3schools website](https://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_forms_inputs) form submission example and am pretty sure my code is the same.This is my code.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Jquery Mobile</title>

<!-- Include meta tag to ensure proper rendering and touch zooming -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Include jQuery Mobile stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">

<!-- Include the jQuery library -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include the jQuery Mobile library -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<style>
  .ui-content {
  margin-top:150px;
  margin-left:500px;
  margin-right:500px;
}

/* For mobile screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .ui-content{
        margin:0px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="chat">
<div data-role="header"><h1>Welcome to the Streamline Chat App</h1></div>
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
   <h3>Select a username to continue</h3>
    <form method="post" action="login.php">
     <label for="username" >Username:</label>
     <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
     <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

login.php

```
<?php
 $username = $_POST['username'];

 echo $username;
?>
```

Am wondering if am doing something wrong. Please help me out. Both files are in the same directory

Comment: Are the index.html and the login.php in the same directory?
Also, you should check to make sure the username is posted first:
`if(isset($_POST["username"]){`...

Comment: @Snake Both files are in the same directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12027991/6240287)

Just needed to add `data-ajax="false"` to the form tag

```
<form method="post" action="login.php" data-ajax="false">
  <label for="username" >Username:</label>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
  <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit">
</form>
```