# Inside a WHILE loop - trying to kick out to a different Location

Tags: php, mysql

I have called a database which has 4 "rows" of data in the field CNT. (2,1,3,1) I want to total these and when I hit a Max number, kick out to another php page.  If the count is below the Max there is another header("Location...) command below.

It will not kick out - can you give me any suggestions

```
    $Count = 0;
    $Max = 5;
    While ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        $Count = $Count + $row["Cnt"];
        If ($Count > $Max) { 
            header("Location: pareAbilities.asp?Who=".$Who."&Logcode=".$LogCode."&A=".$row['A']."&B=".$row['B']."&CNT=".$Count );
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

use [exit()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) after [Header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

```
If ($Count > $Max) { 
   header("Location: pareAbilities.asp?Who=".$Who."&Logcode=".$LogCode."&A=".$row['A']."&B=".$row['B']."&CNT=".$Count );
   exit();
}
```

[PHP - Should I call exit() after calling Location: header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553698/php-should-i-call-exit-after-calling-location-header)

Comment: Thank you - I had tried a break - life is much better now - thanks

Comment: @JohnLawlor: Welcome John Lawlor. And please accept the answer if it was helpful for you! :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what else your doing in the loop.. the following code would be way faster and easier to read.

- Used SQL SUM function to sum up the CNT column
- [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/http_build_query) to build your redirect location
- [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) tidys up your concatenation
- Added [`die`](http://php.net/die) to stop the rest of the page from possible processing

Whats important for your answer is the `die`. Also make sure you have no other output being sent to the browser before this is executing. [`header`](http://php.net/header) can only be sent when there has been no output yet. If you cannot stop the output so easily, try looking into output buffering: [`ob_start`](http://php.net/ob_start) [`ob_flush`](http://php.net/ob_flush)

```
// SUM(CNT) as sum_cnt automagically does the calculation
$query = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(CNT) as sum_cnt, A, B, CNT FROM table");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

if($result['sum_cnt'] > $Max) {
    $querystring = http_build_query( // builds the query string for you
            array(
                'Who' => $Who,
                'Logcode' => $LogCode,
                'A' => $result['A'],
                'B' => $result['B'],
                'CNT' => $result['sum_cnt'],
            )
    );
    header( // sprintf is very nice to keep long concat strings tidy
            sprintf(
                    "Location: pareAbilities.asp?%s", 
                    $querystring
            )
    );
    die(); // Added die here to stop other code from executing
}
```