# How to get Google analytics on my redirect page

Tags: php, analytics, redirect

I have a website that hosts content in English and in German: *www.mysite.com*. I bought a new domain with the same name (*www.mysite.de*) so that it would redirect to the German content on *mysite.com*. Here is what I have in the index page on *mysite.de*:
`<?php`
`header("Location: http://www.mysite.com/index.php?la=de");`
`exit;`
`?>`
How do I track my Google analytics on *mysite.de*, before it redirects? I have the Google analytics script, but don't know where to put it.

Answer (score 0):

By sending the `Location:` header, you instantly redirect your viewer to a different website. My suggestion is to read up on the `Refresh:` header, show him some information like "You'll be redirected in 5 seconds, if it didn't happen, click here" and in the meantime, also display him the HTML code of the script.

Comment: `header("Location: ")` doesn't terminate the page, therefore the script can be added also when there's `Location` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553698/php-should-i-call-exit-after-calling-location-header

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't be surprised to see the browser trying to optimize the process somehow, not even trying to pull the script.