# never show login page after login php

Tags: php, authentication

I am new to PHP
i am making a simple login functionality for user with php & mysql
Here i want to make a simple thing where when a user after "loggingin" if presses back button he shouldn't get the login page back on screen.
I have tried using JS history.forward but its little wierd...

It shows glimps of login page for a second and takes back user to same page from where he presses back button...

How to make a facebook like functionality where login page never appears after loging in even on pressing back button..

Please HELP...:)

```
<?php

include_once 'conn.php';
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header('location:home.php');
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['btnsignin'])) {
    if ($_REQUEST['txtemail'] <> "" && $_REQUEST['txtpass'] <> "") {
        $email = $_REQUEST['txtemail'];
        $pass = $_REQUEST['txtpass'];
        $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register WHERE emailid = '" . $email . "' && password = '" . $pass . "'");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $row['uid'];
            header('location:home.php');
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you added `session_start();` on top ?

Comment: yes added.......i have added it in conn.php with a check of if(!isset($_SESSION)) then session_start

Comment: This won't work. Your `if(!isset($_SESSION))` won't work if you haven't called `session_start();` And why do you want to do a `session_start();` with conditions? No need

Comment: if i donot give conditions it throws warning of session already started..(from the earlier page)

Answer (score 1):

You always want to add `exit;` after the `header()` function to prevent the code block below from execution.

Comment: You definitely should use exit();. Otherwise the script execution is not terminated. 
exit(header("Location: http:// example . com"));
or 
header("Location: http:// example . com");
exit();
See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3553710/3437255

Answer (score 0):

try to use 'AND' in place of '&&' in your sql query.

Comment: use session_start(); as Written by @maulik

Answer (score 0):

you have to start session in php before set it.
you can session start with.

```
 include_once 'conn.php';
 session_start();  //add this line in your code.
   if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
    {
   header('location:home.php');
    }
```

Comment: if you neww in php than you can also follow my blog.
"http://study-php-example.blogspot.in/"
if you like than give me rate on stack overflow.