# How to delete random row using button in PHP?

Tags: php

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
echo "Do you really want to DELETE this field? " ;
?> 
<form method="post">
<input type="submit" name="yes" value="YES" />
<?php
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
if(isset($_REQUEST['yes']))
{
    $id=$row['id'];
    echo $id;
    mysql_query("DELETE from members WHERE id= '$id' "); 
    header("location: view.php");
}
}
?>
<input type="submit" name="no" value="NO" />
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['no']))
{
    header("location: view.php");
}
?>
</form> 
</body>
```

This is my code for delet random row from list view when click on delete button but i m not getting the result so please help me out of these.

Comment: Why are people *still* using `mysql` functions? For the love of god, please switch to `mysqli` or `pdo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass db connection as second parameter to your mysql_query() to delete rows from members table:

```
mysql_query("DELETE from members WHERE id= '$id'" , $dbCon);
```

Here DB connection I mean something this that you have defined in your **connection.php** file:

```
$db_host="localhost";
$db_name="test";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dbCon=mysql_connect($db_host,$username,$password);
```

I hope this solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
mysql_query("DELETE from members WHERE id= '$id' ");
```

to that:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM members WHERE id= '".$id."' ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query `SELECT * FROM members` without ordering will select all the lines in a unpredictable order.

The `if`s in your `while` loop will be either always true or always false:

- if the user click on the YES button, **all** the rows of the table will be deleted as you don't have `exit;` after the `header("location: view.php");` (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553698/php-should-i-call-exit-after-calling-location-header))
- if the user click the NO button, then every iteration of the while loop won't do nothing.

So what you should do:

- Have an hidden parameter in your form containing the id of the field you want to delete.
- Test when the user submit the form that the hidden field is present and sanitized.
- Do not select all the rows of the table
- Delete the rows secificaly by its primary key.
- Call `exit;` after `header("location: view.php");`
- When do an if inside a loop, move it outside the loop if possible if the values do not change.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include("connection.php");

echo "Do you really want to DELETE this field? " ;
?> 
<form method="post">
<input type="submit" name="yes" value="YES" />
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['yes']))
{
    if(isset($_GET['delet']))
    {
        $id = $_GET['delet'];
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = '$id' ");
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
        $did = $row['id'];
        $dname = $row['name'];
        $dphn = $row['phn'];
        /*echo $did;
        echo $dname;
        echo $dphn;*/

        $ins = "INSERT INTO del (mid,name,phn) values ('$did','$dname','$dphn')";
        mysql_query($ins);

        mysql_query("DELETE FROM members WHERE id = '$id' ");
        header('location: view.php');

    }
}

?>  

<input type="submit" name="no" value="NO" />

<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['no']))
{
    header("location: view.php");
    exit;
}
?>
</form>
```