# Capture header in PHP-CGI

Tags: php, http-headers, cgi, fastcgi

I'm attempting to get all HTTP header output from a PHP file, when run via php-cgi. From everything I've read, php-cgi is supposed to output all headers by default. (There's even an option to suppress this, as though it happens automatically.)

I have a PHP file named "test.php", with the following contents:

```
header('Location: http://stackoverflow.com');
echo 'test';
```

But when I run it:

```
php-cgi -f test.php
```

The output is simply:

```
test
```

I expected the location header to be output first. How can I get this header info? I'm using PHP 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.3 (cgi-fcgi).

Comment: You should put an `exit();` after your `header(...);`. It's logical that "test" is the output of your script. Read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553698/php-should-i-call-exit-after-calling-location-header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it! I noticed in the doc definition for the -f argument that it "Implies '-q'".

So this is the solution:

```
php-cgi test.php
```

(Without the -f argument)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are not exiting the script once setting header. You would need to do something more like this

```
header('Location: http://stackoverflow.com');
exit();
```

otherwise code after the header() will be run aswell

Comment: Thanks - that won't help either. I figured it out though, but can't answer my own question as a new user. Turns out the problem was the -f argument when calling php-cgi. Docs say "Implies -q", which suppresses headers!