# Page Redirect PHP

Tags: php, html

Having a file that only auth people can see. And trying to redirect other users before page loads. Following method permits page to load which i do not want.

```
<?php 
session_start();
// Check if person is logged in
if($_SESSION['login'] != 'true'){ //if login in session is not set

 echo "<script>
window.location = 'index.php';
</script>";
}

?>
```

Edit Working Version.

```
<?php 
session_start();
// Check if person is logged in
if($_SESSION['login'] != 'true'){ //if login in session is not set


header('Location: index.php');
exit;
}

?>
```

P.S. Thanks.

Comment: 1. it is wrong redirection 2. you forgot to add `exit`

Comment: Could I suggest using `header("Location: index.php")` to redirect instead of using client side redirection?

Comment: Instead of echoing some Javascript just use `header('Location: index.php');`

Comment: do the redirect with php, no point sending html to browser

Comment: Messed up a little. Now fixed.

Comment: Relying on client-side code for authentication and authorization is basically saying to the user, "Here's all the information you're not allowed to see.  Please don't look at it."

Comment: Just experimenting with pages that are available only for registered users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this instead :

```
<?php 
session_start();
// Check if person is logged in
if($_SESSION['login'] != 'true'){ //if login in session is not set
header("Location: index.php");
die();
}
```

Comment: [Put `exit` after the header call to be safe.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553698/php-should-i-call-exit-after-calling-location-header)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using PHP, you may want to take a look at the [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) documentation. More specifically, setting the `Location` on the header will trigger a 302 Redirect to the page you want it to go to. For example:

```
<?php
    if($_SESSION['login'] != 'true') {
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit;
    }
?>
```

This will tell the page to set the location of the page to `index.php`.  It is important to note, however, that you can only do this **before** any markup is sent to the DOM (such as the `<html>` tag, or any other content for that matter), or else the redirect will fail.

You also will want to add `exit;` after the header change to ensure that any other logic in the PHP file will not execute.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
session_start();

    // Check if person is logged in
if (!$_SESSION['login'])
{
    // Redirect to Login Page
    header( 'location: login.php' );
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Here you're only checking for a loose boolean true, which could be bool true, `1`, `"yes"`, `"no"`, **`"false"`** etc. Since OP is literally writing out "true" or "false", you need to check for that exact occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Send a location header via PHP.
http://php.net/manual/de/function.header.php

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Browser umleiten */

/* Stellen Sie sicher, dass der nachfolgende Code nicht ausgefuehrt wird, wenn
   eine Umleitung stattfindet. */
exit;
?>
```

Programming a foolproof loginsystem is quite hard to achieve. I suggest u use a well tested library instead of reinventing the wheel. However that's outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Nothing is ever foolproof in web security, there's nothing wrong with reinventing a 99% effective solution that takes you 20 minutes to write up when implementing a third party library will weigh down your system