# How to pass the value of a dropdownmenu with php to database

Tags: php, sql, database, select

I have the following form but i cannot get the SELECT (dropdown menu with multiple choice) value to be added in the database. Where am I wrong?
I am using php and I can get all the other value be addedd correctly except the select part. I would like to have a dropdown menu with some choices and when I press "submit" the selected value get into the database.

```
            <form  action="post.php" method="post">

                            <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Customer Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name">
                        </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="number">Mobile Number:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="number" class="form-control" id="number">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="price">Price:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" id="price">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="payment">Payment Type</label>
                    <input type="text" name="payment" class="form-control" id="payment">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="device">Device Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="device" class="form-control" id="device">
                </div>

                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="status">Status:</label>
             <select name="status[]" multiple class="form-control" id="status">
<option value="New">New</option>
<option value="Green">Progress</option>
<option value="Blue">Wait</option>
<option value="Pink">Done</option>
<option value="Yellow">Close</option>
</select>

      </div>             
                 <button type="submit"  name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and the query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ... (name, mail, number, device, price, paymenttype,status,date) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$number', '$device', '$price', '$payment','$status',NOW())";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    // echo "Records added successfully.";
    header("location:....php?message=The customer has been added to the database");

} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

Comment: Change name="status[]" to name="status"

Comment: damn, that was easy,such a stupid! spent one hour and did not see that! thanks!

Comment: Also after header("Location: ....") add exit(); http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553698/php-should-i-call-exit-after-calling-location-header

Comment: thank you for the doubble tip.

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis post as a answer, to receive yor rewards.

Comment: It was an easy one to spot so i made a comment. But if you insist..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the following html code:

```
name="status[]"
```

To:

```
name="status"
```

Also, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553698/php-should-i-call-exit-after-calling-location-header) you should add `exit()` after redirecting you page:

```
header("location:....php?message=The customer has been added to the database");
exit();
```