# Why is my redirect after a succesful user login not working, but instead always loading the login page again?

Tags: php

Why when I input the correct username and password, it not redirect to `index.php` but instead reloads `login.php` ?

Help me to fix the following code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
require_once('conn/conn.php');
$user=$_POST['user'];
$pass=md5($_POST['pass']);
$addonq = "WHERE username='".$user."' AND password='".$pass."'"; 
$user = $koneksi->prepare("SELECT * FROM user ".$addonq."");
$user->execute();
$row = $user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(empty($row['username'])){

echo "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";

}else {
$_SESSION['login_user'] = $user;

header("location: index.php");
}
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<label>UserName :</label>
<input type="text" name="user"/><br />
<label>Password :</label>
<input type="password" name="pass"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value=" Submit "/><br />
</form>
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but: you should be using more than just md5 hashing for passwords. md5 is not secure. Your code also seems to be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: ok, thanks for your suggestion

Comment: I guess this answer will help you to resolve your issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553698/php-should-i-call-exit-after-calling-location-header

Answer (score 1):

You need to add exit(); after header() to terminate the current process.

```
header("location: index.php");
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..
Modify this line

```
$user = $koneksi->prepare("SELECT * FROM user ".$addonq."");
```

to

```
$user = $koneksi->prepare("SELECT * FROM user ".$addonq);
```