# Login that redirects on different pages depending on the usertype

Tags: php

I am working with login module in the website that we are attempting to develop and it is actually not any typical login modules. In my login form there is a dropdown box that you choose if what kind of user you are. There it displays "faculty and staff", "department head" and "supervisor". And each user has different home pages. Here is my `login.php` code:

```
<?php
session_start(); // Starting Session
$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message

if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
            $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
    }else{
        // Define $username and $password
        //$user_type=$_POST['user_type'];
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        // Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
        $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
        // To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
        //$user_type = stripcslashes($user_type);
        $username = stripslashes($username);
        $password = stripslashes($password);
        //$user_type = mysql_escape_string($user_type);
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
        // Selecting Database
        $db = mysql_select_db("cpecs", $connection);
        // SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
        $query = mysql_query("select * from tblaccounts where password='$password' AND username='$username'", $connection);
        $rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

        if ($rows == 1) {
            $_SESSION['login_user']=$username; // Initializing Session
                if ($_POST['user_type']= Faculty) {
                    header("location: userhome.php"); //Redirecting to Faculty Home Page
                }else if ($_POST['user_type']= Department) {
                    header("location: adminhome.php"); //Redirecting to Department Head Home Page
                }else if ($_POST['user_type']= Supervisor) {
                    header("location: supervisorhome.php"); // Redirecting to Supervisor Home Page
                }else{
                    $error = "Oops! It seems that you are not an authorized user.";
                }
        }
    mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
    }
}   

?>
```

I just also called the value of `usertype` from `tbluser_type` in my database to show it in the dropdown box. Here is my code

```
<?php 
    include('connection.php');
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbluser_type";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $option_usertype="";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){         
            $option_usertype= $option_usertype."<option> $row[1] </option>";
        }

?>
```

Comment: $option_usertype=""; 
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
      $option_usertype .= "<option> ".$row['user_type']." </option>";
    }

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

**Please changes code**

```
 if ($rows == 1) {
            $_SESSION['login_user']=$username; // Initializing Session
                if ($_POST['user_type'] == 'Faculty') {
                    header("location: userhome.php"); //Redirecting to Faculty Home Page
                }else if ($_POST['user_type'] == 'Department') {
                    header("location: adminhome.php"); //Redirecting to Department Head Home Page
                }else if ($_POST['user_type'] == 'Supervisor') {
                    header("location: supervisorhome.php"); // Redirecting to Supervisor Home Page
                }else{
                    $error = "Oops! It seems that you are not an authorized user.";
                }
        }
```

**Your mistake**

```
if ($_POST['user_type']=Faculty) {
```

To

```
if ($_POST['user_type'] == 'Faculty') {
```

**Get User type**

```
   $option_usertype=""; 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
      $option_usertype .= "<option> ".$row['user_type']." </option>"; 
    }
```

**$row['user_type'] to Your database field name**

Comment: @newbie Please check you get $_POST['user_type']  ??

Comment: @DelPedro without exit; work proper. after header(...) code not run because redirect to other page.

Comment: $option_usertype=""; 
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
      $option_usertype .= "<option> ".$row['user_type']." </option>";
    }

$row['user_type'] to Your database field name

Comment: It will just execute the first if statement and redirects to the userhome.php even if  i choose to login as department head

Comment: here: `<?php 
    include('connection.php');
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbluser_type";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $option_usertype="";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){         
            $option_usertype= $option_usertype."<option> $row[1] </option>";
        }

?>`

Comment: $option_usertype= $option_usertype."<option value='".$row[1]."'> $row[1] </option>";  Change this line

Comment: @ManishJesani have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553698/php-should-i-call-exit-after-calling-location-header

Comment: @Manish Jesani look, I've change my `login.php` code but it still execute the first if statement.

Comment: @Manish Jesani `if ($rows == 1) {
    $_SESSION['login_user']=$username;
     if ($_POST['usertype']= $usertype['Faculty and Staff']) {
      exit(header("location: userhome.php"));
     }else if ($_POST['usertype']= $usertype['Department Head']) {
      exit(header("location: depthead.php"));
     }else if ($_POST['usertype']= $usertype['Supervisor']) {
      exit(header("location: adminhome.php"));
     }else{
      $error = "Oops! It seems that you are not an authorized user.";
     }
   }`

Comment: @newbie if ($_POST['usertype']== $usertype['database field name'])

Comment: wait I've got an error saying : `Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource` with this code: `$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);` i dont get this code was working a while a go though it does not execute the if statement that i have.

Comment: @Manish Jesani ok, i figured out the first error but now I've got another one. Here `Warning: Illegal string offset 'Faculty and Staff` , `Warning: Illegal string offset 'Department Head'` and `Warning: Illegal string offset 'Supervisor'` .

Comment: @Manish Jesani what do you mean by ['database field name']?

Comment: @newbie Please check you get $usertype and in $_POST['usertype']