# header location not redirecting WORDPRESS

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, header, http-redirect

I'm using word-press and have embedded the following code in the body of the website with hope it will redirect the user the relevant page.

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$e=$current_user->user_email;

$result = mysql_query("SELECT users.user_email
FROM users
WHERE users.user_email='$e'");

$numResult = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($numResult > 0) {
header( "Location: ../Confirm" );
} else {
header( "Location: ../Insert" );
}
```

Unfortunately no redirect happens...any ideas?

Comment: Stop output_buffering?

Comment: removed it and still hasn't done the trick

Comment: try using lowercase L? also  header('Location: ../Confirm'); exit();

Comment: Try adding `exit()` after the header call - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553698/php-should-i-call-exit-after-calling-location-header)

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has its own function to redirect: wp_redirect()

Just make sure your code executes before anything else. A good spot is the header.php file inside the theme, before the  tag.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/