# Getting data from the database to the input type of form but there is an error of undefined variable

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to edit the data that I've inputted to my database using this form.

```
<form method="POST">
                        <table align ="center">
                        <br>
                            <tr><td>First Name: </td> <td><input type="text" name="first" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,}" 
                            title="A-Z only" required value="<?php echo $query2['fname']; ?>"></td> </tr>

                            <tr><td>Middle Initial: </td><td><input type="text" name="middle" 
                            value="<?php echo $query2['middleinitial'] ?>"></td></tr>

                            <tr><td>Last Name:</td><td> <input type="text" name="last"
                            value="<?php echo $query2['lname'] ?>"></td></tr>

                            <tr><td>Contact Number:</td><td> <input type="tel" name="contact" maxlength="11" 
                            value="<?php echo $query2['contactnum'] ?>"></td></tr>

                            <tr> <td>Province: </td><td> <input type="text" name="provincee" 
                            value="<?php echo $query2['province'] ?>"></td></tr>

                            <tr> <td>City: </td><td> <input type="text" name="cityy" 
                            value="<?php echo $query2['city'] ?>"></td></tr>

                            <tr> <td>Username:</td><td> <input type="email" name="usernamee" 
                            value="<?php echo $query2['username'] ?>"></td></tr>

                            <tr><td>Password:</td><td> <input type="password" name="pass" 
                            value="<?php echo $query2['password'] ?>"></td></tr>

                            <tr><td><br> <input type="Submit" name="submitt"></td></tr>
                        </table>
                        </form>
```

Here's my php code.

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){

                            $userid=$_GET['id'];
}

                            if(isset($_POST['submitt'])){
                            $firstname= mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['first']);
                            $middleinitial= mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['middle']);
                            $lastname= mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['last']);
                            $contactnumber= mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['contact']);
                            $province= mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['provincee']);
                            $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['cityy']);
                            $username= mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['usernamee']);
                            $password= mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['pass']); 

                         $query=mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE usertbl SET fname='$firstname', 
                         middleinitial='$middleinitial', lname='$lastname',contactnum = '$contactnumber',
                         province = '$province',city= '$city' ,username = '$username' ,
                         password = '$password' where userid='$userid'");


                          if($query){

                              header('location:employees.php');

                          }

                        $query1=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE userid='$userid'");
                        $query2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query1);
                            }
```

The error that keeps on showing is undefined variable on the input type values of the information on the form. I'm trying to get the data from the database, but I can't seem to get it. What seems to be the problem with this?

These are the errors:

**Notice**:  Undefined variable: query2 in **C:\xampp\htdocs\thesis2\admin\pages\editemployee.php** on line **372**

**Notice**:  Undefined variable: query2 in **C:\xampp\htdocs\thesis2\admin\pages\editemployee.php** on line **375**

**Notice**:  Undefined variable: query2 in **C:\xampp\htdocs\thesis2\admin\pages\editemployee.php** on line **378**

**Notice**:  Undefined variable: query2 in **C:\xampp\htdocs\thesis2\admin\pages\editemployee.php** on line **381**

**Notice**:  Undefined variable: query2 in **C:\xampp\htdocs\thesis2\admin\pages\editemployee.php** on line **384**

**Notice**:  Undefined variable: query2 in **C:\xampp\htdocs\thesis2\admin\pages\editemployee.php** on line **387**

**Notice**:  Undefined variable: query2 in **C:\xampp\htdocs\thesis2\admin\pages\editemployee.php** on line **390**

**Notice**:  Undefined variable: query2 in **C:\xampp\htdocs\thesis2\admin\pages\editemployee.php** on line **390**

Comment: Please post your database query.

Comment: Table structure for table `usertbl`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usertbl` (
  `userid` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `middleinitial` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `contactnum` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `province` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2

Comment: print_r($query2['middleinitial']) see if you get any data also post it

Comment: @user7693696 I mean the query in your PHP code. Where do you define `$query2`?

Comment: sorry didn't saw that i didn't put the code. i've edited my post

Comment: I think you may be able to access it like this $query2[0]['middleinitial']

Comment: we need more info about those errors to know exactly whats going on , add this : `if (!$query || !$query1 ) {
   printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}` then if nothing come out of it try this : `if (!$mysqli->error) {
   printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}`

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\thesis2\admin\pages\editemployee.php on line 395
Errormessage: That's what it says.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is your order of evaluation. You are trying to query only when the form is submitted (as well after the redirection -- which makes no sense as the query will never be reached since you did a redirection right before it).

This is how I would do it

```
<?php
$userid = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null;

if (isset($_POST['submitt'])) {
    $firstname = trim($_POST['first']);
    $middleinitial = trim($_POST['middle']);
    $lastname = trim($_POST['last']);
    $contactnumber = trim($_POST['contact']);
    $province = trim($_POST['provincee']);
    $city = trim($_POST['cityy']);
    $username= trim($_POST['usernamee']);
    $password= $_POST['pass']; // leave it as is

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "
        UPDATE usertbl 
        SET fname = ?, middleinitial = ?, lname = ?, contactnum = ?, province = ?, city = ?, username = ?, password = ?
        WHERE userid = ?
    ");

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssssssssd', 
        $firstname, $middleinitial, $lastname, $contactnumber, $province, $city, $username, $password, $userid);

    $updated = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

    // redirect if user is updated
    if ($updated) {
        header('Location: employees.php');
        exit;
    }
}

// note: the next lines of code appear OUTSIDE the previous if statement (1)

// cheating here as you should definitely be using prepared statements here also!
if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE userid = '$userid'")) {
    $query2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
}
?>

<!-- HTML form -->
```

**Side-remarks:**

1. There's no reason really to use `mysqli_real_escape_string`. You should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).
2. [Always `exit` after doing redirecting.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3553710/1022914)
3. I don't normally use MySQLi as their syntaxes is ridiculously ugly. [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) is way easier and cleaner to use.