# pick a random link and then continue to go to link

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to make a page pick a link and then go to link there are 2 links that I am trying for it to decide from I have read [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) and used whats in there to make this

```
$input = array("https://order.abcgameservers.com/aff.php?aff=47", 
"https://discord.gg/CjzZRBq");
$answer = $rand_keys = array_rand($input, 1);
echo "header('Location: $answer')";
```

it echoes header('Location: 1')

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Carcigenicate how do I make it go to the link once its picked it

Comment: You don't `echo` a `header()`. It should simply be `header('Location: '.$input[$answer]);`, that's it! Also take note that there's been added an index. Have a look at the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php - and note that `$answer` would hold the index, not the value, of the selected item.

Comment: @Qirel it goes to websitelink.com/$answer then brings up a 404

Comment: @Qirel he has an issue with the random key slection to

Comment: @rtfm Aye, I edited my comment just as you commented ;-)

Comment: or you could just add a third answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the [PHP.net website](http://php.net/array_rand), array_rand() outputs a random key in an array set and not the value it self. So in your case, you need to use the provided key to retrieve the corresponding value. $input[$answer].

Also, the redirect should not be in an echo. [header() is a function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) and can't work the way you used it in your example. Although, I am pretty sure you did that just to debug your script lol

Try this:

```
$input = array("https://order.abcgameservers.com/aff.php?aff=47", "https://discord.gg/CjzZRBq");
$answer = array_rand($input, 1);
header('Location: '.$input[$answer]);
```

Answer (score 2):

There's three things to note about this.

1. `header()` should not be `echo`'ed, it returns `void`.
2. `array_rand()` will just return the *key* of an element, not the value.
3. You should always use `exit;` after `header("Location: ..");` (although it might not be relevant if its the end of the script).

From the manual (emphasis mine)

> Picks one or more random entries out of an array, and **returns the key** (or keys) of the random entries.

After implementing those changed, your code would look like this

```
$input = array("https://order.abcgameservers.com/aff.php?aff=47", "https://discord.gg/CjzZRBq");
$answer = $rand_keys = array_rand($input);
header('Location: '.$input[$answer]);
exit;
```

You'll notice that the `header()` has been altered in two ways: The echo has been removed (and the quotes that went along with that), and that it targets `$input[$answer]` instead of `$answer`.

Alternatively, you can use `array_flip()` to flip the value/index pairs. If you use `array_rand()` on that, you'd get a random value!

```
$answer = array_rand(array_flip($input));
header('Location: '.$answer);
exit;
```

- [PHP manual: `array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)
- [PHP manual: `array_flip()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)
- [PHP manual: `header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)
- [php - Should I call exit() after calling Location: header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553698/php-should-i-call-exit-after-calling-location-header)