# Do I need to use exit() after redirecting my user off the page on which the script is executed?

Tags: php, jquery

After successful registration, my user is redirected to the home page using:

```
echo
    "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
        window.location.href='../index.php';
    </script>";
```

Do I need to follow this with

```
exit();
```

or is redirecting the user enough?

[EDIT] to help solve how to use die()/exit() alongside javascript in the same php file

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("form").submit(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var username = $("#register-username").val();
        var email = $("#register-email").val();
        var password = $("#register-password").val();
        var confirmPassword = $("#register-confirm-password").val();
        var submit = $("#register-submit").val();

        $(".form-message").load("../shared/_registerAccount.php", {

            username: username,
            email: email,
            password: password,
            confirmPassword: confirmPassword,
            submit: submit

        });
    });
});
```

end of PHP script (success path):

```
        else
        {
            $errorEmpty = $errorUsername = $errorEmail = $errorPassword = $errorConfirmPassword = false;

            $hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sss", $username, $email, $hashedPassword);

            mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

            session_start();
            $_SESSION['register-success'] = 'You have successfully registered! Please verify your email before logging in.';

            $registrationSuccessful = true;

            die('<script type="text/javascript">location.assign("../index.php")</script><a href="../index.php">Home</a>');
        }
```

jQuery that follows PHP script in same file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var registrationSuccessful = "<?php echo $registrationSuccessful; ?>";

    if (registrationSuccessful)
    {
        $("#register-username, #register-email, #register-password, 
            #register-confirm-password").val("");
    }

</script>
```

Comment: `exit` will stop the PHP execution when called. It would depend on the rest of the script and what needs to occur. Also note that is JS, not jquery. You could use `header` instead of the JS redirect.

Comment: When the redirection occurs everything else has been finished. It is the final part of the success path of the script.

Comment: It won't add anything, and it possibly could break the DOM so I'd say no.

Comment: I asked this question because exit() seemed to prevent some of my jQuery animations from activating. Taking it out of the script fixed it, but I wanted to make sure it was okay to do this.

Comment: Yes, that is because anything after `exit()` won't be put into the DOM.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php - Should I call exit() after calling Location: header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553698/php-should-i-call-exit-after-calling-location-header)

Comment: @RamlalS No, this is not using `header`. This is using a redirect **after** the page loads.

Answer (score 2):

You're assuming that **JavaScript** will be *always* available (or enabled) on all users browsers. I would **heavily** suggest utilising the native `header` **PHP** function:

```
die(header("Location: ../index.php"));
```

Or, if that's not a possibility (for whatever reason), at least give users an alternate way if **JavaScript** isn't enabled:

```
die('<script type="text/javascript">location.assign("../index.php")</script><a href="../index.php">Home</a>');
```

Comment: This is a very good idea, though the only issue it brings for me is that it doesn't allow me to clear my form values with jQuery. Everything else works, and clearing the form is purely for aesthetic value, but it would be nice to figure out how to get both to work together.

Comment: If you include how your form is formatted and _"cleared"_ I would be happy to help you out :)

Comment: To be clear, I have javascript inside script tags after the php code in the same file as the script. This does not run after die/exit is called.

Comment: It has been updated, hopefully with enough relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend `exit()` ,If there is any further code after redirection.If you don't have any code then you don't have to.
if you are using any alert before `exit` then stay page using `refresh` otherwise alert message in fraction of sec.