# How to fix 'php skipping my if statement'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I got an html/php page which you can select only 2 or below from the checkbox values. I limited the selection using javascript. But my concern is if someone tried to use developer tools they can simply disable my script and select more values from the checkbox. So I thought that I need to count how many POST data am I getting from the checkbox.

I tried using the count() in php to count the post and tried to echo the count and I get the right number. I then tried using an if statement that will echo if the selected is more than 2. It worked but when I use header('Location:') it skips it.

```
$countpres = count($_POST['pres']);
if($countpres>=3){
   header('Location:../index.php');
}
for($i=0;$i<$countpres;$i++)
{
$sql1 = "UPDATE candidate_list SET vote_count= vote_count + 1 WHERE candidate_number = '". $_POST['pres'][$i]. "' ";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
}
```

I need to go to index.php if ever the user tries to send more than 2 of the options.

Comment: They can select 2 values. sorry

Comment: Yes I have tried that. But why am I not being headed to index.php

Comment: and yes. All of my checkbox are named pres[]

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump()`ing `$countpres` to see what the value is?

Comment: I have also tried

$countpres = count($_POST['pres']);
if($countpres>=3){
   echo "hello";
}

And it does echo hello.

Comment: You're not meant to use relative paths in Location redirects.

Comment: You need an `exit()` after the `header()` or it will carry on - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553698/php-should-i-call-exit-after-calling-location-header

Comment: Thank you Nigel. exit() solved my problem.

Comment: Watch out! Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. For more information check [What is SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) and [How to prevent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For php7

```
header("location: index.php",  true,  301 );  exit;
```

For php5

```
header("Location: index.php");
exit();
```

If still it not work and faild to redirect thn use:

```
echo '<script>windows.location = "index.php";</script>'; exit();
```

Or

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.top.location='index.php';</script>"; exit();
```

**Replace index.php with your file**