# Two records insert into Mysql Database other than one

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a Question. Instead of having the record insert rather once, It inserts twice into the DB table. I am using a Javascript function to send the Data to a PHP , Now it saves the data to a Database, No doubt , but rather than have one Record, It saves twice. And i do not have a reason as to why this is so.

My javascript used to save data looks like this :

```
function submitFormData(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'submit_request.php';
    var fullname = document.getElementById("fullname").value;
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    var address2 = document.getElementById("address2").value;
    var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
    var state = document.getElementById("state").value;
    var telephone = document.getElementById("telephone").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var vehicle_type = document.getElementById("vehicle_type").value;
    var vehicleNo = document.getElementById("vehicleNo").value;
    var visit_date = document.getElementById("visit_date").value;
    var visit_purpose = document.getElementById("visit_purpose").value;
    var whom_tosee = document.getElementById("whom_tosee").value;
    var login_time = document.getElementById("login_time").value;

    var params = 'fullname='+fullname+'&address='+address+'&address2='+address2+'&city='+city+'&state='+state+'&telephone='+telephone+'&email='+email+'&vehicle_type='+vehicle_type+'&vehicleNo='+vehicleNo+'&visit_date='+visit_date+'&visit_date='+visit_date+'&visit_purpose='+visit_purpose+'&whom_tosee='+whom_tosee+'&login_time='+login_time+'';

    var txt = 'Please confirm the following Information\n FullName : '+fullname+'\n Address : '+address+'\n Address2 : '+address2+'\n City: '+city+'\n State: '+state+'\n Telephone: '+telephone+'\n Email: '+email+'\n Vehicle Type: '+vehicle_type+'\n Vehicle #: '+vehicleNo+'\n Visit Date: '+visit_date+'\n Visit Purpose : '+visit_purpose+'\n Who To see : '+whom_tosee+'\n Login Time : '+login_time+'';
    var response = confirm(txt);

    if(response == true){
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
               // alert('Sending Data');
                var finalurl = url +'?'+params;
                window.location = finalurl;
            }
        }
        xhr.send(params);
    }else{
        window.location ='e-vmsreserve.php';
    }

}
```

And the PHP used to save the Data into the DB looks like this

```
<?php
        session_start();
        if(!isset($_SESSION['userID']))
        {
                header("location: index.php");
        }
?>

<?php
require_once('inc/config.php');

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die ('Cannot connect: '.mysqli_error());

$query = "SELECT * FROM evmsdbusers WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['userID']."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die('Bad Query: '.mysqli_error($con));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

$fullname = $row['fullname'];
$username = $row['username'];
$designation = $row['designation'];
}


?>

<?php

require_once('inc/config.php');

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) or die('Cannot connect, Reason:'.mysqli_error());

$fullname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['fullname']);
$address = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['address']);
$address2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['address2']);
$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['city']);
$state = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['state']);
$telephone = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['telephone']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['email']);
$vehicle_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['vehicle_type']);
$vehicleNo = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['vehicleNo']);
$visit_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['visit_date']);
$visit_purpose = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['visit_purpose']);
$whom_tosee = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['whom_tosee']);
$login_time = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['login_time']);
$invitee_username =$username;


$sql = "insert into new_reservation (fullname,address,address2,city,state,telephone,email,vehicle_type,vehicleNo,visit_date,visit_purpose,whom_tosee,login_time,visitor_username) values ('".$fullname."','".$address."','".$address2."','".$city."','".$state."','".$telephone."','".$email."','".$vehicle_type."','".$vehicleNo."','".$visit_date."','".$visit_purpose."','".$whom_tosee."','".$login_time."','".$invitee_username."')";
    mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die ('Bad Query, Reason: '.mysqli_error($con));

    $message = "Appointment Reserved!";
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
    echo 'alert("'.$message.'");'; 
    echo '</script>';

?>
```

Now what i do not seem to understand is why I am having 2 records,Though not duplicate but it should have only one record.

Comment: Why you use `$_GET` method while post data, also use prepare statement to prevent SQL injection

Comment: GET with insert is open invitation for SQL injection, second, this will insert on every refresh due to `$_GET`

Comment: @RobinSingh, is $_GET the reason for duplicate records?

Comment: No that is not the reason

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code is wide open for SQL injection, using `$_GET` is open invitation for SQL injection. I suggest you to use Prepared statement, this will prevent your code for SQL attack.

**Issue in your code** is `window.location = finalurl;` this line, this will redirect to same php file with same params, and your query will insert twice due to `$_GET` values.

So, you just need to show your response when you got `response 200`, no need to redirect on same url `'submit_request.php'` with same params.

**Some useful links:**

[Are PDO prepared statements sufficient to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection)

[Prepared Statement Manaul](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

One more suggestion always `exit();` after `header();` otherwise your code will not terminate.

[php - Should I call exit() after calling Location: header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553698/php-should-i-call-exit-after-calling-location-header)

Comment: it does not save into the data should i take window.location away, it does not even redirect, should i add it back, it saves , but i have 2 records

Comment: @Sam: yes remove this part and second tell me your php code SELECT and INSERT both of them in 1 file??

Comment: the second file is 'submit_request.php' which is supposed to access the GET request as created from the javascript, So yes, the SELECT is suppose to use sessions to fetch information and i would use in the INSERT Statement. So yes they are one file.

Comment: @Sam: ok then you are doing one more mistake here, do not stablished database connection twice

Comment: @Sam: second use `echo $sql; exit;` before `mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die ('Bad Query, Reason: '.mysqli_error($con));` and share the result, either your query print once or twice please hsare

Answer (score 1):

Thank You DevPro, Somehow I managed to see where the error was. when performing a get request, it should be in the pattern url+'?'+parameters

I remembered that and tried it in my code, somehow it saves fine now and no Duplicate records or double insert. In case someone needs it in future :), PHP Remains the same.

I did it like this **xhr.open('GET', url+"?"+params, true);**

```
function submitFormData(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'submit_request.php';
    var fullname = document.getElementById("fullname").value;
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    var address2 = document.getElementById("address2").value;
    var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
    var state = document.getElementById("state").value;
    var telephone = document.getElementById("telephone").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var vehicle_type = document.getElementById("vehicle_type").value;
    var vehicleNo = document.getElementById("vehicleNo").value;
    var visit_date = document.getElementById("visit_date").value;
    var visit_purpose = document.getElementById("visit_purpose").value;
    var whom_tosee = document.getElementById("whom_tosee").value;
    var login_time = document.getElementById("login_time").value;

    var params = 'fullname='+fullname+'&address='+address+'&address2='+address2+'&city='+city+'&state='+state+'&telephone='+telephone+'&email='+email+'&vehicle_type='+vehicle_type+'&vehicleNo='+vehicleNo+'&visit_date='+visit_date+'&visit_date='+visit_date+'&visit_purpose='+visit_purpose+'&whom_tosee='+whom_tosee+'&login_time='+login_time+'';

    var txt = 'Please confirm the following Information\n FullName : '+fullname+'\n Address : '+address+'\n Address2 : '+address2+'\n City: '+city+'\n State: '+state+'\n Telephone: '+telephone+'\n Email: '+email+'\n Vehicle Type: '+vehicle_type+'\n Vehicle #: '+vehicleNo+'\n Visit Date: '+visit_date+'\n Visit Purpose : '+visit_purpose+'\n Who To see : '+whom_tosee+'\n Login Time : '+login_time+'';
    var response = confirm(txt);

    if(response ==true){
        xhr.open('GET', url+"?"+params, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                alert('ok');
            }   
        }
        xhr.send(null);
    }

}
```

Thanks everyone!