# $_GET is not set even though the id is shown in the url

Tags: php, get

My update function is not working the browser is showed $_GET['ticketID'] is not set.

```
    <form action="ticketResolve.php" role="form" method="post">
           <input type="hidden" name="ticketID" value="<?=$ticket['ticketID']?
          <label for="username">Sender_name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sender_name"placeholder="Enter Username" value="<=$ticket['sender_name']>"readonly>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
         label for="firstName">Contact</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact" placeholder="Enter First Name" value="<?=$ticket['contact']?>" readonly>
          </div>
         <br><br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-orange-1" name="resolveTicket">Resolve</button>
  </form>
```

this is my form

ticketID is from this loop and transfer it to the ticketResolve.php page where the ticketID is use to get the details of the ticket, which works data from the database populate the input tags.

and this is the code in the ticketResolve.php page

```
$ticket = getTicketDetails($_GET['ticketID']);

if(isset($_POST['resolveTicket'])) {

    resolveTicket($loggedUser['userName'], $loggedUser['userID'], 
$_POST['ticketID']);
    header("Location: admin_viewTickets.php");

}

<input type="text" value="<?=$text?>"> //this is showing 1
```

the "resolve" field should change from 0 to 1

Please help thank you

Comment: Think you need another equals in `ticketResolve.php?ticketID<?=$ticket['ticketID']?>` => `ticketResolve.php?ticketID=<?=$ticket['ticketID']?>`

Comment: Yes after `?ticketID=`

Comment: still not working sad

Comment: Check the HTML on the page to see what it is being set to, then if it's OK - check your page `print_r($_GET);`

Comment: BTW - you should always follow a `header()` call with `exit()` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553698/php-should-i-call-exit-after-calling-location-header

Comment: @NigelRen Location header.

Comment: @JohnMacasinag Can you update your original post with the updated code? This way we can see if you updated it properly and new people coming to help don't need to read all the comments to check what you've tried so far.

Comment: @JohnMacasinag  Could you post (in the body of the question) the _rendered_ HTML of one of these buttons?

Comment: it print "1" where is that "1" coming from?

Comment: @JohnMacasinag  To use [print_r()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) for assignment instead of direct output, you need to pass `TRUE` as the second argument.

Comment: print_r() is returning the correct ID which is 14

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `=` in the href attribute, change it to

```
<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="ticketResolve.php?ticketID=<?=$ticket['ticketID']?>">view</a>
```

Comment: it's post because It's an update function, what variable are you referring to?

Comment: but it's the same

Comment: Do you have some rewriting rules applied? If yes check QSA flag.

Answer (score 0):

Update it is now working there was a typo error in my sql command -_- thank you for your help guys. All it took was a little nap.