# PHP login page does not detect form data correctly

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create a login system that allows people to login. You can register on a different webpage and enter the credentials on this page to login and get redirected to another site but despite entering the correct credentials, I don't get redirected at all and it just uses my 'else' code. I tried moving the following piece of code in and out of the other if statements but that didn't help. I also tried changing the operators from && to || on the code below but that just gave me a blank screen. I also tried detecting whether $_POST('userName') and $_POST('password') were empty and give an alert when they are but that also didn't work at all.

Currently I'm not worried about the security yet because it's not for commercial use.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == 1) {
  header('Location: (link to different site)');
}
```

My HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Serif:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <header>
      <h1 style="color: #333; font-family: PT Serif; font-size: 30px">title</h1>
    </header>

    <section class="container">
      <form method="post" action="index.php" id="login">

        <h1 id="h1" style="font-family: Raleway; color: #333">Login</h1>
        <div class="msg">
        </div>

        <div>
          <label for="name" style="font-family: Raleway;">Name:</label>
          <input class='input' type="text" id="name" name="userName">
        </div>

        <div>
          <label for="password" style="font-family: Raleway;">Password:</label>
          <input class='input' type="password" id="password" name="password">
        </div>

        <div>
          <label for="register" style="font-family: Raleway;"><a href="link">No account yet?</a></label>
        </div>

        <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>

    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$error = '';

$link = mysqli_connect('localhost','dbuser','dbpass','dbname');

if(empty(trim($_POST["userName"]))){
  $error = '<script>alert("Please fill in both your username and password.")</script>';
}

elseif(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
  $error = '<script>alert("Please fill in both your username and password.")</script>';
}

elseif(isset($_POST['userName']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $userName = $_POST['userName'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $sql_u = "SELECT Username FROM table WHERE Username='$userName'";
    $sql_p = "SELECT Password FROM table WHERE Password='$password'";

    $res_u = mysqli_query($link, $sql_u);
    $res_p = mysqli_query($link, $sql_p);

    if($userName == $res_u && $password == $res_p) {
        $_SESSION['userName'] = $userName;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
  }  
}

if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == 1) {
  header('Location: link');
}

else {
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Serif:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <header>
      <h1 style="color: #333; font-family: PT Serif; font-size: 30px">title</h1>
    </header>

    <section class="container">
      <form method="post" action="index.php" id="login">

        <h1 id="h1" style="font-family: Raleway; color: #333">Login</h1>
        <div class="msg">
        </div>

        <div>
          <label for="name" style="font-family: Raleway;">Name:</label>
          <input class='input' type="text" id="name" name="userName">
        </div>

        <div>
          <label for="password" style="font-family: Raleway;">Password:</label>
          <input class='input' type="password" id="password" name="password">
        </div>

        <div>
          <label for="register" style="font-family: Raleway;"><a href="link">No account yet?</a></label>
        </div>

        <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>

    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `header('Location: ...');` should always be followed by `exit;` in PHP.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php - Should I call exit() after calling Location: header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553698/php-should-i-call-exit-after-calling-location-header)

Comment: `SELECT Password FROM table WHERE Password='$password'` ? Your table is actually called `table`? What if two users use the same password? Do the username and password check in _one_ query

Comment: Don't ever store plain text passwords. PHP has [password_​hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_​verify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: `I'm trying to create a login system that allows people to login.` - this code in the question has multiple significant security problems, don't ignore them. e.g. using the password `blah' OR 1 = 1` you can log in as anyone. Some keywords to search for: `prepared statements`, `sql injection`  [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). It's kinda beyond the scope of stack overflow to address all the flaws - Don't make this up as you go along, find a tutorial/example to follow :).

Comment: If you're making a login system, then the whole point of it is to enforce security. You can't then say that you're not very concerned about security. It makes a nonsense of the whole effort. Besides, correctly-implemented login systems aren't that easy to create - a few well-used, well-tested frameworks and plugins - maintained by experienced people with relevant expertise in this field - have done this the right way, fixed the bugs, and are re-usable. Don't re-invent the wheel, use an existing turnkey solution and spend your time adding some unique value to your application instead.

Comment: Why beginners or near-beginners constantly pop up here with their hopeless "make a login system" projects is beyond me. It's not a topic for beginners. Use your imagination and think of something genuinely useful to implement, but where a few little security issues wouldn't be the end of the world. A login system is not that place.